# Install an application on Guest OS in Virtual Box

Tags: windows, virtualbox, installation, virtual-machine

I'm very new to Visualization. In my workstation I don't have admin rights. I just wanted to install SQL Server 2008R2. Fortunately I have Virtual Box installed. So I installed Windows Server 2008 as the guest OS in VirtualBox as I had the disk image. Now I have a downloaded setup of SQL Server (Not a Image) in my hard disk but the thing is I can access those setup files only from my host OS (Win 7). I tried to access it from my guest OS but failed.

Can anybody tel me how to run (from Windows Server) SQL Server setup which is in my host computers file system?
Even for installing an application in guest OS, do I need a Image file?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Guest VM can ping your workstation. If it can't, check your network configuration.

Then, put the setup in a share on the Host PC and install from the share on the Host PC using the Guest VM.